# how to add content for each line on certain character with powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to add `:` on text files on certain number of characters for example:

**Original text file**

```
ASDWEQRWEASDKLOEWQPEWQLJKEWQ
QWEKFKLWEJKJSDFJLKSADJAKLSJASDLAKJS
QWEJKLJSMCJSDJAIQEWJKLASDJA
```

Output file with add content of `:` on second and tenth position (character)

```
AS:DWEQRWEA:SDKLOEWQPEWQLJKEWQ
QW:EKFKLWEJ:KJSDFJLKSADJAKLSJASDLAKJS
QW:EJKLJSMC:JSDJAIQEWJKLASDJA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt') -replace '^(.{2})(.{8})', '$1:$2:' |
    Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```

`^(.{2})(.{8})` matches the first 2 and the next 8 characters at the beginning of a string (`^`), and captures them in two groups, so they can be referenced as `$1` and `$2` in the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

This will take a .txt file and insert `:` at position 2 & 10 on every line and output it to a .txt file.

```
Get-Content -Path C:\YourTextFile.txt `
    | ForEach-Object { $_.Insert(2,":").Insert(11,":") } `
    | Out-File -FilePath C:\YourOutPutFile.txt -Append
```